# What's the proper order in which Django cache middleware should be added?

Tags: django

I'm trying to add caching to my Django project and I'm failing to understand documentation on [middleware ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#order-of-middleware). Consider the following MIDDLEWARE list, which is mostly default:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'simple_history.middleware.HistoryRequestMiddleware'
]
```

If I'm understanding [this piece of documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache) correctly, I'm supposed to add three new entries to MIDDLEWARE list. Is there more than one proper ordering for my case?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/cache/#order-of-middleware

Comment: @DanielRoseman I linked to this piece of documentation in my question - I'm finding it vague and I don't understand why there's no example. Would you like to rephrase it and show how it would work in my case?

Comment: This is a reasonable question — it could be clearer where to put the `UpdateCacheMiddleware` and `CommonMiddleware` and `FetchFromCacheMiddleware` even just among the [startproject middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware). The ordering of the cache ones vs. `ConditionalGetMiddleware` is also relevant here.

Answer (score 7):

The default [startproject middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/middleware/#activating-middleware) are:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

The three [per-site cache middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache) are given as:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]
```

And when we're discussing caching there's also [ConditionalGetMiddleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/middleware/#django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware) which is related to [conditional view processing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/conditional-view-processing/):

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware'
]
```

The question is then, what is the [proper order](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#order-of-middleware) to combine all these into one single `MIDDLEWARE` list? The Django documentation gives two rules specific to caching:

- `UpdateCacheMiddleware` must come **before** "any other middleware that might add something to the `Vary` header" (and `SessionMiddleware`, `GZipMiddleware`, `LocaleMiddleware` do)
- `FetchFromCacheMiddleware` needs to run **after** middleware that varies `Vary`

While it could be more subtle if you have additional custom stuff, the most natural way based on the defaults is to just bracket all the other middleware inside the cache ones. But we'll leave `SecurityMiddleware` up top since afaict it just checks/redirects some stuff that would be better done by something [e.g. nginx] wrapping Django itself anyway.

The `CommonMiddleware` was included at presumedly the right place in the `startproject` list already, so that one's easy.

The `ConditionalGetMiddleware` is tricker; a separate section of [Middleware ordering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/middleware/#middleware-ordering) hints say it goes "after GZipMiddleware […]" but overall "before any middleware that may change the response" which is a bit odd but whatever…. (Apparently the GZip middleware is [discouraged/problematic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/middleware/#module-django.middleware.gzip) anyway.)

At the end here's what I get:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',   # Caution: BREACH attack?
    'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]
```

Note that there's at least one [odd interaction](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32531) between `ConditionalGetMiddleware` and `UpdateCacheMiddleware` in that the former may prevent the latter from actually caching the render if/when that render gets replaced with a 304 response.

So perhaps even better would be:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
]
```

…avoiding Gzip and handling HTTPS/HSTS stuff in the HTTP server layer instead.